# Can't connect Hudson with Subversion to download a directory

Tags: svn, hudson

I have an SVN repository installed at 
https://advisorycenter.unfuddle.com/svn/advisorycenter_mssql

And I have Hudson with SVN plugin installed. Now I want to create a job, which downloads files from SVN repository.

When I provide 
"https://advisorycenter.unfuddle.com/svn/advisorycenter_mssql" in "Repository URL" 
field, everything works fine. But when I provide "https://advisorycenter.unfuddle.com/svn/advisorycenter_mssql/trunk" 
I am getting the following error:

ERROR: Failed to check out https://advisorycenter.unfuddle.com/svn/advisorycenter_mssql/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: authentication cancelled
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:177)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:580)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:286)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:274)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I know for sure that the URL

https://advisorycenter.unfuddle.com/svn/advisorycenter_mssql/trunk

works fine in my TortoiseSVN client

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, never mind. I created a fresh job, entered https://advisorycenter.unfuddle.com/svn/advisorycenter_mssql/trunk on both job configuration and credential screens; and it works fine. This looks to me like a minor defect in Hudson 3.0.0 though. So if you have the same problem, just start a new job project.